# Problem with React-Native Output View Component

Tags: reactjs, view, output, react-native

this code does not Display the **list(places)** which places i added to it using **add**_**Button**.

Generally working of this code is this that i **input text** into this react-native app using **TextInput** Component, after this i press the **Add** Button to add this text into a **list(places)**, after this it automatically display all the entered text.

e.g if i enter the **place by 1st time** it only display **that text**, but if i enter **another text** it displays that text as well as the **first one.**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, StyleSheet, Button, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component
{
  state = {
      placeName: "",
      places: []
  };

  placeNameChangeHandler=(val)=>
  {
    this.setState({
      InputValue: val
    })
  };  

  placeSubmitHandler = () =>{
    if(this.state.placeName.trim() === "")
    {
      return;
    } 
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        places : prevState.places.concat(prevState.placeName)
      };
    });
  };


  render()
  {
    const placesOutput = this.state.places.map((place, i) =>(
      <Text key={i} backgroundColor = 'black' >{place}</Text>
    ));
    return(
      <View style={Styles.container}>
        <View style = {Styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder = "Search place?"
            value = {this.setState.placeName}
            onChangeText = {this.placeNameChangeHandler}
            style={Styles.placeInput}
          />
          <Button 
            title='Add' 
            style = {Styles.placeButton} 
            onPress = {this.placeSubmitHandler}
          /> 
        </View>
        <View>{placesOutput}</View> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1, 
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },

  inputContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection : 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems:'center'
  },

  placeInput: {
    width: "70%"
  },
  placeButton: {
    width: "30%"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not 100% correct, but I'll write it down.

This seems to happen because of `setState`.

First.

Change to `value = {this.setState.placeName}` to `value = {this.state.placeName}`

```
     <TextInput
        placeholder = "Search place?"
        value = {this.state.placeName}
        onChangeText = {this.placeNameChangeHandler}
        style={Styles.placeInput}
      />
```

Next.

Change setState in `placeNameChangeHandler`

```
placeNameChangeHandler=(val)=>{
    this.setState({
      placeName: val
    })
};
```

And

Add Initializing `placeName`

```
placeSubmitHandler=()=>{
    if(this.state.placeName.trim() === "")
    {
      return;
    } 
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        places : prevState.places.concat(prevState.placeName),
        placeName : ""
      };
    });
  };
```

Sorry for my stupid English.

I hope you understand :)

Comment: Thank so much Brother,

Comment: it's okay you're English is far better than me,
Thanks Once again.
Actually I'm New in React_Native, That's Why i don't understand it Fully Till Now.